# How to ignore nulls while doing matching in python?

Tags: python, regex, null, python-re

I have a data frame, I am using regex to check the pattern of the data of a column while doing this there are nulls in it. Due to nulls, it was able to match. I don't want to drop them either replace it with some other value. I want to ignore it, though I tried getting errors or getting NONE as output. How do we ignore the null values while doing a match?

code:

```
df =
  a        b    c
0 rt-0000  abc  1
1          vb   2
2 rt-1234  abc  3
3          op   4
4 rt-123   oip  5

format = 'rt-\d\d\d\d'
if df['a'].isnull().any():
          continue
          correct_df = df[df[key].str.match(format )]
          wrong_df = df[~df[key].str.match(format )]
```

The output gives: `NONE`

when I tried without ignoring nulls I got a error: `'Cannot mask Naan/Null values'`

excepted output:

```
corrected_df:
      a        b    c
    0 rt-0000  abc  1
    1          vb   2
    2 rt-1234  abc  3
    3          op   4
wrong_df:
4 rt-123   oip  5
```

I tried using different if condition but I end up with the same output. Can we ignore the null values?

Comment: I don't see any nulls in your data

Comment: @MonkeyZeus oops! I forgot to add them. I have edited it along with the excepted output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['rt-0000',np.nan,'rt-1234',np.nan,'rt-123'],
                  'b':['abc','vb','abc','op','oip'],
                  'c':[1,2,3,4,5]})

         a    b  c
0  rt-0000  abc  1
1      NaN   vb  2
2  rt-1234  abc  3
3      NaN   op  4
4   rt-123  oip  5
```

You can simply use:

```
correct_df = df[df.a.str.match(format, na=True)]
wrong_df = df[~df.a.str.match(format, na=True)]
```

That gives your result:

```
         a    b  c
0  rt-0000  abc  1
1      NaN   vb  2
2  rt-1234  abc  3
3      NaN   op  4
```

and

```
        a    b  c
4  rt-123  oip  5
```